# How to set people picker to readonly in infopath?

Tags: infopath, people-picker, read-only

I am using sharepoint 2013. At one list I have implemented my custom edit page in infopath. I am using some sections and some rules. I would like to set a people picker field to readonly but I cannot find it!! On a normal textbox there is an option to set it on readonly. Can somebody please help to set this people picker to readonly?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to show people picker as read-only, instead you should show a read-only textbox with User Name or Login Name!

Answer (score 2):

I dont think its possible to do it, but the following would be the work around.

1. Add a “People Picker” to the Form;
2. Add a “Text Box” control to the Form, and set its properties as following:

a. Default Value: AccountId. (you specify the default value to the People picker field)

b. Refresh value when formula is recalculated : checked.

c. Display: Read-only. (Make it read-only, so that the user cannot change its value by UI )

Add Rule to the “Text Box” control. When “This field changes”, do “set a field’s value ”, or submit data.

REF: [People Picker](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/96c72659-2570-4fbb-904e-9f3bd84ad241/infopath-people-picker-action-rule)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: InfoPath is telling me that a textbox can't have the value of a person or group. Is there another workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

We can set the People picker control in read only mode using the below steps

1. Select the people picker field
2. create new rule - formatting
3. In the Condition set  "The Expression"  to ture()
4. Finally Diable this control under formatting.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to show people picker as read-only, instead you should show a read-only textbox with User Name or Login Name!

PS: Some controls, such as the Person/Group picker, don’t have a read-only toggle in their control properties. However, setting the View to read-only will work for these controls

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Calculated field and set the value equals to your people picker field. Make sure the Calculated field value is updated every time. This Calculated field will always be 'Read Only'

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by dragging in the display field from the people picker (DisplayName) into my form, which generated a "Repeating Section" in my form with a text box control that I could set to disabled using a rule.

I'm using a separate view for approvals; the people picker is only applicable when the form is initially submitted, so this may not apply to all cases.

Here's how I did it:

1. Deleted the people picker control from my "Approvals" view (which was a copy of the default "Edit" view)
2. In the Fields pane, switched to the "advanced view"
3. Expanded the people picker field and found the the "DisplayNames" field:
   [image: Underlying people picker fields]
4. Drug the field into the form, which created a "Repeating Section" and a text box:[image: Result of dragging underlying people picker field to form]
5. Formatted the repeating section to what I liked and set a conditional formatting rule on the text box, which allows you to set the "Disable this control" for the people picker value!

I would post more images for the walkthrough, but do not have the reputation yet.